# Convergence of sequence of minimizers

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Suppose $\mathcal{X}$ is compact, and consider an optimization problem: $$\max_{x \in X_{n}} f(x)$$ where $f$ is a continuous function, and $X_{n}\subseteq \mathcal{X}$ is a sequence of compact sets converging to some set $X \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ (for example, in the Hausdorff metric). Now let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence of minimizers of $f$; i.e. $f(x_{n}) = \min_{x \in X_{n}} f(x)$. Note that $f(x)$ may have multiple minimums.

I am interested in conditions under which the arbitrary sequence of minimizers $\{x_{n}\}$ converges to a point in $X \subset \mathcal{X}$. Does anybody know?

**Further Background:**

I often see the statement: **by compactness of $\mathcal{X}$, we can assume without loss of generality that $x_{n} \to x \in  \mathcal{X}$.** My problem with this statement is that it uses the fact that $\{x_{n}\}$ has a convergent subsequence, and says nothing about whether my original sequence converges.

This discussion is also related to the theorem of the maximum, which I believe can be used to establish that $X^{*}(n) = argmin\{ f(x) : x \in X_{n}\}$ is upper hemicontinuous. However, similar to the point above, it seems to me that upper hemicontinuity is not enough to guarantee that $x_{n} \to x$, only that it has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: I may need to think about this more, but off the top of my head, you may need to restrict $f$ to have only one minimizer on the set $X$. For example, take $X_n=[0,1]$ for all $n$ (and thus $X=[0,1]$), $f(x)=x^4-x^2$, and $x_n=(-1)^n/\sqrt{2}$. Since this sequence of minimizers is alternating, it doesn’t converge. If $f$ has two minimizers on $X$, I think this kind of construction will always be possible.

Comment: My understanding of the statement in bold is, in fact, that it refers to the existence of a subsequence with the property stated, i.e. one can assume that one started with that subsequence right in the beginning. If you want to prove existence in $X$, this is usually sufficient. Unless you really need convergence of the original sequence (e.g because $x_n$ is related to $x_{n+1}$ in some way you cannot give up, or if you want to combine existence with uniqueness) for some reason I'd read it that way.